# How can I deprogram the key fob of my Explorer?

Tags: ford, keyless-entry, fob

I have a key fob which is programmed for a 2001 Ford Explorer.  I've recently programmed it to a 2006 Ford Explorer hoping that this new programming would deprogram it from the 2001 Ford Explorer.

Unfortunately, now the key fob works on both cars simultaneously.  Is there any way to deprogram the key fob on the 2001 Explorer?

Comment: Is this the factory key fob? If not, it would help to know the brand and maybe the model as well.

Comment: @dlu it's not the one that came with the car. It's just a random one I bought on amazon that was listed as working with the 01 Explorer. I didn't even check if it worked with the 06 Explorer before programming it for that one.

Comment: Do you know if it is an "official" Ford key fob? Even if it is not the one that came with the car. Knowing that would help anybody trying to help you with the procedure. For VW at least, there appear to be some vendors who make third party fobs.

Comment: @dlu it looks from my purchase history as though it's a Ford one. The title of the listing has Ford in it.

Answer (score 1):

Go through the same motions to program it for the 2001 as you did the 2006, but don't use it to program it. It's the vehicle which is actually programmed, not the fob. Once you go through the programming for the 2001 it will reset. Any fob which will then be used for it should be programmed or none will work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried doing that earlier and it didn't work. Specifically, I turned the ignition 8 times until the doors locks clicked. What should I do after that? How long should I wait before removing the key?  I waited 10 seconds last time and it didn't work.  Once I removed the key from the ignition the fob still worked on the car.

Comment: You only have the single key fob?

Comment: I have another old faulty one somewhere for the 01 Explorer. But since it's faulty and I don't use it, we could say yes, I only have one key fob for the 01 Explorer (which now works on the 06 Explorer too). I have a separate fob that works for the 06 Explorer only but I want to put that away as a backup and use the 01 fob exclusively on the 06.

Comment: Honestly I'm not very good with cars and I need steps to follow in order to correctly try something.  Can you please give me a step by step account of your suggestion? Specifically, once I turn the ignition 8 times and I hear the locks click, what should I do next?